# Connect two elements by a straight line or elbow connection

Tags: html, css

I would like to place two elements on a web page at any random location. They won't overlap however. What I would like to do is have a line drawn from the side of one of these elements to the side of the other. If the elements are aligned a straight line can be drawn otherwise an elbow connection needs to be drawn.

I can think of one solution by adding a third element that has two adjacent cells (such as a table) and then just set the border to create either a straight connection or an elbow connection. The size of the third element would need to be adjusted so that two sides touch the two other elements.

I'm wondering however if there is something in css that can do this without the need for a third element.

Comment: Is there anything that you have tried? Can you provide some code which may work partly?

Comment: And to answer the question, This cannot be done without a third element, and even with a third element would be very hard to implement using only CSS. You'd probably need Javascript to achieve this.